# Multiple css styles in shiny R markdown

Tags: r, shiny, r-markdown

I create a lot of R Markdown files using the shiny runtime that have multiple interactive components, usually each one is wrapped in `shinyUI()`.  I would like to be able to style the different interactive sections separately, but haven't been able to figure out how.  I have tried using `includeCSS()` in different `fluidPage()` components, but the first one is always loaded and the rest ignored.  Can this be done easily?

Answer (score 1):

I've never tried having multiple shinyUI() on the same page, but here's what I can think of:

Wrap each shiny app in an html tag with a different id, load all the css in one script, and in the css rules just specify which id the rule should fall under

Comment: You mean something like `tags$html(id = 'inserto', uiOutput(ns('markdown')))` ?